# How objects are created in c#

Tags: c#, object, static

We can`t create an object of a c# static class. So how we were able to use the members of a static class?
Are there any in memory object that is create on run time?

Comment: read chapter 3 (Types Fundamentals) of CLR via C# book

Comment: It's unclear what you're after here. What *exact* aspect are you interested in? Down to the CLR memory allocation, garbage collection etc, or just what the order of constructors, field initializers etc?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your response. Actually i am learning c# and i need to know everything about object creation. All from memory allocation to constructors called.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan for you answer. i would consider reading this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading a book about this and this is what I memorized from the book. I think remembering this much is good enough. If I need to know more, I will just read about it again.

The GC always keeps a pointer to a memory location in the heap so it knows where to allocate the next object. This is called the Next Object Pointer or NOP.

Let's say you have this class

```
public class Employee
{
    private int empId

    public void Work() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is how the instance will look like:

```
--------------------------  -4 bytes 
|  Object Header Word    |
|------------------------|  +0 bytes <------Object reference is pointed here as well
|  Method Table Pointer  |
|------------------------|  +4 bytes for method tabel pointer
|  Storage for empId     |
|------------------------|  +8 bytes (4 for empId) (12 in total (from -4 to +8))
```

The Object Header Word is used for many purposes such as synchronization, GC, hash code and finalization.

The Method Table Pointer is a pointer which points to an internal CLR data structure called simply a Method Table or MT. MT points at another structure called EEClass. The MT and EEClass work together to call virtual methods, interface methods, determine the type of runtime objects etc.

Oh and a last note, on 64bit systems, the Object Header Word is 8 bytes (not 4). Also even if you had one `bool` in the above class instead of `int`, it will still take up 12 bytes because objects in the heap are aligned to the nearest 4 byte multiple.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: What is in the "Object Header word"? I can't find a a description anywhere.